# PowerShell merging data from multiple CSVs

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

I have a bunch of CSV files containing information about DHCP scopes (100+ files, one for each server). I wish to merge the data from all into a new table. There are ways to merge the CSVs but that's not good enough, because one the most important piece of information is not included inside the individual CSV files...that of the server name. The server name is coming from the filename itself. Hence the approach to build a new table.

My issue is that the properties for SubnetMask, StartRange, EndRange, ScopeID and State are being output in the same "cell". I managed to do it for the ScopeName (i.e. managed to get one ScopeName per line), but not sure how to approach the rest.

```
$outputTable = $null
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\Discovery\" -Filter *Scopes.csv
Write-Host $files
ForEach($file in $files)
{
    $scopeFile = Import-Csv $file

    ForEach ($scopeName in $scopeFile.Name)
    {
        $outputTable += @(
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                    ` DHCPServer=$file.Name.ToString().Split(".")[0];
                    ` ScopeName=$scopeName;
                    ` SubnetMask=$scopeFile.SubnetMask;
                    ` StartRange=$scopeFile.StartRange;
                    ` EndRange=$scopeFile.EndRange;
                    ` ScopeID=$scopeFile.ScopeID
                    ` State=$scopeFile.State
                    }
                )
    }
}

$outputTable | ft
```

Current output:

[image: Output]

Expected output:

```
DHCPServerName,ScopeName,SubnetMask,StartRange,EndRange,ScopeID,State
server1,london,255.255.0.0,192.168.0.1,192.168.0.254,192.168.0.1,Active
server1,london,255.255.0.0,192.168.1.1,192.168.0.254,192.168.1.1,Active
server1,london,255.255.0.0,192.168.1.1,192.168.0.254,192.168.1.1,NotActive
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your input data and the expected output?

Comment: add example of the structure of your csv files and not in a image

Comment: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is exponentially expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [calculated property with `Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to add the file's `Name` as a new column of your Csv:

```
$merged = foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\Discovery\ -Filter *Scopes.csv)
{
    Import-Csv $file.FullName | Select-Object @{
        Name = 'DHCPServerName'
        Expression = { $file.Name.Split(".")[0] }
    }, *
}

$merged | Format-Table
```

Comment: This is truly the work of the devil! Thanks :)

Comment: @NadimAJ  my pleasure, happy to help :)!